# How this video play Icon got generated on html button, without giving any source?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, html5-video

```html
<button id="play" aria-label="Play" role="button">►<!--how this icon is working--> 
</button>
```

*I got this code from codepen, I'm building custom UI video player using just html, css, and js. Now this above code got me so confused, how come icon is working without providing any source to it. can you pls explain how this play icon is created*

for full code you can check here on [codepen](https://codepen.io/HarishCalvin/pen/xxOEypE)

Comment: btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    media.currentTime = 0;
})

js part is having this code..

Comment: Maybe there is something in your question we are missing. But I think you'll find ▶︎ (U+25B6 U+FE0E) is just a unicode symbol :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner html of the button is set to that symbol in the Javascript file

Answer (score 2):

It does it in the js! Look there. It gets the button and the video by id to play it.

Comment: wow thanks now got it! it would be very helpful if can you tell me *how to drag progress bar in video player*. !!